# grub2, using variables to pass to linux entry

Tags: grub2

I have the following variable in a grub.cfg file.

```
BOOT_PARAMETERS="rootwait rootfstype=ext4 rootimage=$BOOT_ROOT_IMAGE_NAME root=$ROOT_DEVICE console=none intel_idle.max_cstate=1 quiet"
BOOT_ROOT_INITRD=(hd0,gpt2)/boot1/initrd
BOOT_ROOT_KERNEL=(hd0,gpt2)/boot1/bzImage
```

I want to pass these parameters into a menu entry.

```
menuentry 'pc'{
linux $BOOT_ROOT_KERNEL $BOOT_PARAMETERS
initrd $BOOT_ROOT_INITRD
}
```

The `BOOT_ROOT_KERNEL` and `BOOT_ROOT_INITRD` works fine, but the parameters doesn't work. I'm not sure how it breaks the boot, but this menu entry will not boot. If I replace `$BOOT_PARAMETERS` with the actual contents of the variable (without quotes, it works).

Also, the following works as well:

```
linux $BOOT_ROOT_KERNEL "$BOOT_PARAMETERS"
```

However, the `/proc/cmdline` includes those quotes, and I don't want to break applications that are reading this output.

How do I get this to work?

```
linux $BOOT_ROOT_KERNEL $BOOT_PARAMETERS
```

**Edit**: In grub command line, if I do `echo $BOOT_PARAMETERS`, the machine flash reboots. If I do `echo "$BOOT_PARAMETERS"`, it prints normally.

**Edit2**: It seems to have to do with large environment variables. Doing `set TEST="SFSFESFSEFDFUIHI rg s rjg sreuigsrgi sig isdfjgs dfkgd"`, followed by an `echo $TEST` will *sometimes* cause it. It happens at a certain length/combination, and I can't put my finger on it. If it doesn't happen on first try, keep appending stuff to `TEST`, then the `echo $TEST` will eventually cause a flash reboot.

Comment: You do not edit grub.cfg. You edit /etc/default/grub. See this part : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2  You could edit 40_custom, but then would just use the correct boot stanza, no need for variables. Grub is sensitive to boot stanzas that are correct.

Comment: This is an embedded device, and for reasons, we HAVE to pass dynamically built environment variables to the boot process in grub.

Comment: Also the boot parameters are correct. If I pass values directly (instead of environment variables), it works.

Comment: Could it be just a space at end of first variable or beginning of second?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but today i make a search and fall back here.

This is the solution i use:

define the variable in bash script:
`readonly ISONAME=$(ls -1 -c "/mnt/isoLinux" | head -n 1)`

include the `menuentry` in a `cat << EOF` in order sh make variable substitution
define the variable in grub:
`set isofile="$ISONAME"`

use the variable in grub:
`loopback loop \$isofile`
the `\` prevent from sh to do variable substitution

my full script `/etc/grub.d/40_isoLinux`

```
#!/bin/sh

readonly ISONAME=$(ls -1 -c "/mnt/isoLinux" | head -n 1)

cat << EOF

menuentry "Iso linux"  {
    set isofile="$ISONAME"
    set dri="free"
    set lang="fr_FR"
    set keytable="fr"
    set timezone="Europe/Paris"
    insmod ext4
    search --no-floppy -f --set=root \$isofile
    probe -u \$root --set=diskIsoUuid
    set diskDevice="/dev/disk/by-uuid/\$diskIsoUuid"
    loopback loop \$isofile
    linux  (loop)/boot/vmlinuz-x86_64  img_dev=\$diskDevice img_loop=\$isofile driver=\$dri tz=\$timezone lang=\$lang keytable=\$keytable copytoram
    initrd  (loop)/boot/amd_ucode.img (loop)/boot/initramfs-x86_64.img
}

EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

I refer you to GNU Grub documentation. See the [echo command](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/echo.html). It details how to include variables, new line, carriage return, tabs etc.

To echo your $TEST variable try this:

```
ECHO ${TEST}
```

In short, put your variable name after a $ dollar sign and between { } curly braces. Hoping your machine won't play up if you try this.